# getting an index of a selected item in a list apple script

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write an apple script with a large list and I want to prompt the user to select an item from the list and then the script should display an index of this item. Getting the script to prompt the user to select from list wasn't a problem, but I can't get an index of a selected list item.

Here is the example code and a loop I tried so far

```
set cities to {"New York", "Portland", "Los Angelles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento", "Honolulu", "Jefferson City", "Olimpia"}
set city_chooser to choose from list cities
set item_number to 0
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in cities
    set item_number to item_number + 1
    if i = city_chooser then
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
display dialog item_number
```

It just gives me the number of items in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vanilla AppleScript does not provide an *`indexOfObject`* API. There are three ways:

1. An index based loop which iterates the list and returns the index when the object was found.
2. Bridging the list to AppleScriptObjC to use the `indexOfObject` API of `NSArray`.
3. If the list is sorted a binary search algorithm which is very fast.

---

A fourth way is to populate the list with this format

```
1 Foo
2 Bar
3 Baz
```

and get the index by the numeric prefix but this is quite cumbersome for large lists.

---

**Edit:**

There are a few issues in the code. The main two are that `choose from list` returns a list (or `false`) and you are comparing a string with the index variable, an integer.

Try this

```
set cities to {"New York", "Portland", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento", "Honolulu", "Jefferson City", "Olympia"}
set city_chooser to choose from list cities
if city_chooser is false then return
set city_chooser to item 1 of city_chooser
repeat with i from 1 to (count cities)
    set city to item i of cities
    if city = city_chooser then exit repeat
end repeat
display dialog i
```

Comment: I tried to do a loop like this, but out of the things I tried so far nothing worked. How do I make a loop that does that then?

Comment: Well, edit your question and add what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the index using AppleScriptObjC like so:

use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "Foundation"

```
property NSArray : class "NSArray"

-- usage example with different data types. ASOC handles all the conversions
my firstIndexOf:3 inList:{"a", "hello", 3, date "Wednesday, February 12, 2020 at 12:00:00 AM", true}

on firstIndexOf:anItem inList:aList
    set anArray to NSArray's arrayWithArray:aList
    return (anArray's indexOfObject:anItem) + 1
end firstIndexOf:inList:
```

The repeat loop vadian outlined is fine for most cases. You only want to use this with large list where the performance advantages of ASOC start to be meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @vadian's answer, here is a simple script for testing (and returning) an index value or -1 if it is not found.

```
set cities to {"New York", "Portland", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento", "Honolulu", "Jefferson City", "Olympia"}
set chosen to "Polrtland"
if cities contains chosen then
    repeat with idx from 1 to (count cities)
        if item idx of cities = chosen then exit repeat
    end repeat
    set the result to idx
else
    set the result to -1
end if
```